# Linux. Technologies that allow to work with scanner from WEB page?

Tags: linux, scanning

I have to deal with scanner from WEB-page. I can use Active-X (TWAIN / WIA) and Silverlight (WIA) on Windows (may be Flash also?). What technologies may I use on Linux to access scanner from web-page?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can also develop [NPAPI plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) that interact with scanner (TWAIN/WIA). That also support scripting and you can access to JavaScript methods, objects and DOM model in scope of your HTML page. For IE you can develop IE plugin like toolbar.
For example, there's an open source project called [FireBreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) which allows you to write a plugin for IE (ActiveX) and NPAPI (Firefox, Opera, Chrome etc.) from a single codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Applet. Have you seen JTwain: http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/faq.php. It's a commercial tool but might be of help to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

you can try SANE for scanning in Linux. It's open source: http://www.sane-project.org/ .